# Copy file from Linux to Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-transfer

I feel a bit strange asking this question - but I did not find via Google:

**What is the standard way for copying (file-transfer) files from one Linux machine to another? Preferably via a GUI**

Of course there are `scp` and `samba` but scp is probably slow due to encryption and samba is for sharing files with windows clients.

Comment: Besides SCP the next most common option would be FTP.

Comment: you can speed up `scp` with the `-C` option. It activates `compression`. This provides that you are limited in band width and not cpu usage.  Another way for more speed is using `rsync -z` which is similar to `scp -C`.

Comment: OK after your  comments I finally tried scp for a 40GiB file and the speed is about 100MiB/s (around 800mb/s) - This is amazing :) Especially after I experience low performance with sshfs in combination with git

Comment: Pls see my answer too, which uses ssh in a GUI format, as you requested.

Comment: `rsync` is the faster and more robust form of `scp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the answers provided in the two comments above are perfectly right, the OP stated:

> Preferably via a GUI

So here it goes. You open your File Manager (I use KDE, hence dolphin for me, but it is nearly identical in Gnome or other desktops), split the screen into two halves with the `Split` command, click on the second half, which, for the moment, displays the files on your own pc, then search under `Control -> Location Bar-> Editable location`; in the bar that just appeared you write:

```
       fish://myname@remote_system
```

The weird protocol `fish` stands for file transfer over ssh. If you have enabled passwordless login on the remote system, you are already in, otherwise you will be asked for a password. At this point the view in the second half changes, and you are shown your own home directory on the remote system.

You can now navigate graphically on both halves of the window, drag and drop, whatever.

Comment: Usually I'd would recommend the standard SFTP (`sftp://`) rather than this FISH hack...

Comment: Great Input - fish://user@machine doesn't work though - but got me thinking about sftp://user@machine

Comment: @grawity can you expand a bit on this, pls? I am not aware of any problem with `fish`....

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: SFTP is a standard, documented, sub-protocol of SSH, while "fish://" is KDE's custom thing built around running shell commands on the server (e.g. to download a file, regular `cat` is used), which is ... somewhat fragile.

Answer (score 0):

After the great input from @MariusMatutiae, @h0ch5tr4355 and @ap0 I'd like to report what I tried and use now:

- scp is very fast and seems to be limited by the network bandwith (I copy with about 100MiB/s (800 mps)
- sftp://user@host seems to be a bit slower 80MiB/s but can be used with the files tool in Ubuntu (and I am sure it works with most file managers)